# Code formatting bug for Bash scripts with array size expression

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, source-code

The bash script line:

```
for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#v1parts[@]} ; i++ )); do
```

doesn't format properly. The # is incorrectly interpreted as the beginning of a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a problem with [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) which stackoverflow uses to render code; not with stackoverflow itself.